# Небольшая программа на C++

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, численные-методы

### Доброго времени суток всем!

Давно учил С++, уже его подзабыл, но сейчас необходимо решить задание. Буду благодарен любой помощи!

**Задание:**

Есть нелинейное уравнение `cos(2/x) - 2sin(1/x) + 1/x = 0` , необходимо посчитать корень `х` на неком участке `(а,b)` с точностью `eps` (методом деления отрезка пополам). `a,b,eps` - вводит пользователь (консольный интерфейс)

**Алгоритм расчета:**

1) `x = (a+b)/2;`

2) Если `f(a) * f(x) > 0` , в в следующей итерации `a = x` , иначе `b = x;`

3) Продолжать пока длина отрезка не станет меньше чем `eps`.

Есть такие наброски:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <cmath>


double f(double x)
{
    return cos(2.0 / x) - 2 * sin(1.0 / x) + 1.0 / x;
}
int main()
{
    double a, b, eps,fx,fa,x;
    printf("\n a = ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("\n b = ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("\n eps = ");
    scanf("%f", &eps);
    do
    {
        x = (a + b) / 2;
        if (f(x)*f(a) > 0) a = x;
        else b = x;

    } while (fabs(b - a) >= eps);

    printf("\n x = %-10.3f", x);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тут лабки не делают.

Comment: Ну вы же уже все написали! осталось изложить это с помощью операторов C++...

Comment: Нет, п.2 Вашего алгоритма написан неверно. Его следует перенести в начало программы - до итерационного цикла: так проверяют лишь правильность начального отрезка ab. Дихотомия - не лучший способ определения корней функций.

Answer (score 4):

В принципе, вы же все сделали правильно. Можно добавить кое-что по мелочи...

Во-первых, надо убедиться, что `a<b` - это упрощает жизнь.

```
if (a > b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }
```

Затем для начала проверим, есть ли решение:

```
double fa = f(a), fb = f(b);
if (fa*fb > 0)
{
    puts("Метод неприменим");
    exit(1);
}
```

Теперь вам не нужно вычислять на каждом шаге функцию лишний раз:

```
while( b - a > eps )
{
    x = (a+b)/2.0;
    if (fa*f(x) > 0)
        a = x;
    else
        b = x;
}
```

В принципе, можно отдельно проверять, не равно ли `f(x) == 0`.